# how can i call MySQL stored procedure from django?

Tags: mysql, django, stored-procedures

I am a beginner to Django. I tried to call the stored procedure from django with the cursor but it said cursor does not have ‘return_value’ attribute.

```
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.callproc('check_schedule', [new_sch.bus_id, new_sch.depart_time, new_sch.arrive_time, 0])
            if cursor.return_value == 1:
                result_set = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.close()
```

Comment: So what happened when you did this?

Comment: It said cursor doesn’t have ‘return_value’ attribute

Comment: Well what makes you think it does? That's not mentioned in the docs at all.

Comment: Sorry sir..I found that on google....can u pls point me how to correct?